# How can I find the view mapped to certain url in django with pycharm?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pycharm

I'm debugging multiple apis built with django rest framework , How can I find the views mapped to a certain URL?. I'm currenty using pycharm so is there any plugin than can help

EX:

> in url : /api/users/business-segment/

how can I know the view that maps to this url ?

Answer (score 1):

I agree there could be a more automatised way, but I look in `urls.py` files starting from the left. So the `urls.py` file from the `users` app will guide me to `business-segment`, which is most likely a `ViewSet`.

Comment: Thank you , I found answer on stackoverflow that mentions that I can use the below
 

from django.urls import resolve

match = resolve('/api/users/business-segment/')
print(match.func)
print(match.url_name)

but I was searching if pycharm provides a plugin or away to get the view